# Exclude resources from dependency jar

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I have a maven projects let's call it A which has dependency on two maven projects B, C. Both B and C has a file in resources with same name let say x.xml. I want to exclude this x.xml from B(I don't want to write exclude it from B's jar in M2) jar when building A's War. means it should be present in B's jar but when this jar is copied to A's war should not available. Is it possible?

Comment: When you are building war it will contain two jar's with same file that is the problem which file will be picked at run time one can't be sure so i want only one jar may have it as we can exclude dependencies is there a way so that i can exclude it's resources while keeping it's dependency?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Delete file from dependency jar using truezip-maven-plugin for example

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>truezip-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.1</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>remove-a-file-in-sub-archive</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>remove</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <configuration>
            <fileset>
                <directory>target/mywar-webapp.war/WEB-INF/lib/dependency.jar/dirName/</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>fileName.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </fileset>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```